# A&M Form Table Field Submission

Tags: plugin-amforms

I'm trying to submit a form containing items from a users' cart, using A&M forms, but cannot seem to populate the table field with the items. I'm using the code below:

```
{% for item in cart.lineItems %}
    <input type="hidden" name="fields[selections][{{loop.index}}][col1]" value="{{item.qty}} x {{item.description}}">
{% endfor %}
```

For some reason, though, it's creating the rows in the table, but not actually populating it with any content. Any idea what to do to get it to work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a bit late to this, but I think it's because your `{{ loop.index }}` is not **[0-indexed](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/for.html#the-loop-variable)**, which is necessary for the array.  It should look like this:

`<input type="hidden" name="fields[selections][{{ loop.index0 }}][col1]" value="{{ item.qty }} x {{ item.description }}">`

You also need an extra valueless `hidden` field above the loop to collect all the values into one array:

`<input type="hidden" name="fields[selections]" value="">`

You can see a fuller example on how to format the HTML for all fields of all types on this **[StraightUpCraft](https://straightupcraft.com/articles/craft-cms-field-guide-twig?view=input)** page.  Scroll to the very bottom for tables.